# MySQLInstallerConsole legacy authentication method argument

Tags: mysql

What is an argument to set authentication method to legacy authentication method in MySQLInstallerConsole?

What I currently use

```
MySQLInstallerConsole install server;$dbVersion;X64:*:passwd=SomePassword;openfirewall=true;serverid=1;enable_tcpip=true;port=3306;datadir=SomeDir; -silent
```

But I can figure out what is an argument for legacy method...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
MySQLInstallerConsole Community  install server;$dbVersion;X64;*;passwd=SomePassword;openfirewall=true;serverid=1;enable_tcpip=true;port=3306;datadir=SomeDir; -silent
```